# Export dynamic Google map as KMZ

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, kmz

I have a database with lat\long values and I use google maps api v3 to plot these points on a map and draw a 30 mile radius around these points. All I have is a bunch of circles drawn on the map with info windows if you click on these circles.

I need to export this map as a .kmz file so that I can put it on my web server and make it available to our marketing website to import as a layer into their site.

Is this possible without re-inventing the wheel? My initial map is drawn in php, I query the database and get a json object that I traverse in javascript to plot the points and draw the circles.

Thank you
Jack

My current map as it appears:
[image]

Comment: What does your code/map look like?  You can certainly save the geographic data as KML (then zip that to KMZ). [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kml-support/dXrHA_CkZIE